# HSQL Server Issue with jdbc

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

I have **HSQL server 2.3.4** and I am trying to use hsql jdbc connectivity jar **2.2.9** to aceess the HSQL database but I am getting **End of file** exception.
The Servr is working pretty fine when I am using hsql jdbc connectivity jar **2.3.4** with hSQL Server 2.3.4. 
Can somebody explain the reason for no backward compatibility

Answer (score 0):

New features are introduced in each new version of the database engine. Sometimes the addition of new features requires changes to the network protocol used for exchanging data between the client and server. These changes break backward compatibility.

It is recommended to use jars of the same version on client and server.

Comment: I agree to your point but where is it officially mentioned about the same.Its based on our assumptions that means